# Expanding a User model property in Jenkins REST API

Tags: python, api, rest, jenkins

I am trying to extract last login details of a user by using Jenkins REST APIs, upon querying for the URL https://jenkinsurl/user/someusername/api/json I receive a response similar to the one shown below.

```
{
      "_class" : "hudson.model.User",
      "absoluteUrl" : "https://jenkinsurl/user/someusername",
      "description" : null,
      "fullName" : "someusername",
      "id" : "someusernameid",
      "property" : [
        {
          "_class" : "someProperty1"
        },
        {
          "_class" : "someProperty2"
        },
        
        {
          "_class" : "org.jenkinsci.plugins.saml.user.LoginDetailsProperty"
        },
      ]
    }
```

Now the details I am looking for are under LoginDetailsProperty which can be found in the [source here](https://github.com/jenkinsci/saml-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jenkinsci/plugins/saml/user/LoginDetailsProperty.java). I have seen the details been used in the Jenkins UI when I open **user/someusername/configure** to modify user details or create access token. How can I expand the LoginDetailsProperty and extract the lastLoginTimestamp value for a particular user using REST APIs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to extend the plugin code so that the timestamp gets exported, like this:

```
import org.kohsuke.stapler.export.Exported;
[...]
@Exported
public long getLastLoginTimestamp() {
[...]
```

Comment: Does this mean that I would need to build and package the plugin myself and then re-install it again to my Jenkins environment?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. I think the only other alternative is to skip the JSON api altogether and extract the information with a Groovy script.

Comment: Hmm...makes sense. I have never used Groovy before and was trying not to go down that path but I guess that's a way better approach to the problem. Any suggestions where to look for help?

Comment: Hm, in the end it's probably easier to modify the plugin. Re-building it is easy, and if you submit the modification to the official repo, you will have a permanent solution and you contributed to the development.

If you want to go for Groovy, then you need to dig into the object model for creating a script that yields the wanted information, then use the REST API for running that Groovy. I'd only go that path if you expect to use the Groovy/Jenkins combination in the future again.